# Getting response()->json() as undefined in console.log() in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I was working on overtrue/laravel-follow package and was using ajax call to follow a user and unfollow.
scripts file includes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    $('.btn-follow').click(function() {
        let user_id = $(this).data('id');
        let object = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/follow',
            data: { user_id: user_id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.success);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

User Controller Follow method:

```
public function follow(Request $request)
    {
        $authUser = Auth::user();
        $user = User::findOrFail($request->user_id);

        if ($authUser !== null && $authUser instanceof User) {
            $response = $authUser->toggleFollow($user);
            return response()->json(['success' => $response]);
        }
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/follow', 'UserController@follow')->name('user.follow');
```

I'm getting undefined object in the console and no object with attached and detached.
What is the problem

PS: It is surprising that method is still working and follow unfollow is working behind the scene

Comment: Have you tried to print only `data` in `console.log()`? Share your `console.log(data)` response.

Comment: I did that too and it gives and empty object

console.log(data) response:
{success: null}

Comment: Your `$response` is not getting data I suppose. please try `echo "<pre>";print_r($response);die;` before `return` statement and check data in `network` tab of chrome console.

Comment: Yes you are correct $response is not getting data. The network tab is empty even though status is 200. What should I do?
PS: But the method is working properly but still the mounted and unmounted state I want to use jquery to change text aren't visible.

Comment: it means `$authUser->toggleFollow($user);` is getting null. Please check if you have proper data in `toggelFollow($user)` function.